# Adding some color to trees in a picture (Photoshop)

Tags: photo-editing, color-management

I'm just getting into photo editing so I pulled a photo off of google and tried to edit it. I'm happy with the edits, but I want to add more green color to the trees to give it a bit more color and pop. I am also more than happy to take any suggestions about how to make it look better. Any help would be great, thanks! https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIK3w.jpg

[image]

Comment: Are we looking at the same image? The trees are in shadow. Pop it too much and things will look fake.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something with "luminosity masks", which is a technique to select pixels in proportion of their luminosity (*):

- Duplicate the image, and convert it to B/W
- Using the Curves tool, blow the whites
- Color-invert the image (so now what was very dark is nearly white)

[image]

- Use that as a selection (in Gimp you open the Channels list, right click any RGB channel, and make it a selection). This creates a progressive selection.
- Activate the original image and use Curves again to boost the dark parts

[image: Imgur]

(*) Google this for your favorite image editor. For Gimp I recommend [this excellent tutorial](https://patdavid.net/2013/11/getting-around-in-gimp-luminosity-masks.html))